# how to fix ionic cordova build android for google service plugin?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have searched for this a lot and tried to short out the problem.. i have followed to change version also inside android.properties but it's not working.

When i do `ionic cordova build android` it gives following error:

```
Script '/My-path-to/platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/android-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"
```

Here is my android.properties :

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/android-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-support-google-services/android-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/android-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
```

Any help/suggetion would be very much appreciated..if need any detail please let me know.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

get the GoogleService.json File from firebase console -> project overview -> project settings -> Your apps -> googleservice.json button and paste the file inside yourapp/platfom/android/ or yourapp/platfom/android/app/

Comment: googleservice.json file is already at your suggested path. but no luck

Comment: have a look https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1878

Comment: if not workes try reinstall all the plugins at latest version

Comment: Hey @Parvej Mallick thanks for you help.. it seems issue with firebase auth and google serivce..when i remove firebase auth it works  finally got problem of version. 

Comment: can you elaborate the solution ,when I'm adding phonegap push plugin facing the similar issue